Is it possible to have a class but then also call in objects of that class to use within functions?
void MixedFractions::Subtraction() {
  class MixedFractions MixedFrac1, MixedFrac2, MixedFracSum;
  int wholeNum1, wholeNum2, wholeNumSum;

  wholeNum1 = MixedFrac1.GetWholeNum();
  wholeNum2 = MixedFrac2.GetWholeNum();

  wholeNumSum = wholeNum1 - wholeNum2;

  MixedFracSum.SetWholeNum(wholeNumSum);
}

What I am trying but I'm not sure if I am implementing it properly since it is only part of a project instead want to make sure I am approaching this right instead of doing this wrong. Since I am thinking of two ways this will go, it will either just use the default constructor and not use the values I'm trying to implement. Likewise, it won't be able to set the values that im trying to pass through the function.
edit sorry for the confusion, but yes this is part of a bigger class definition but maybe I should have phrased my question as how do I get my objects to function if they are user-generated instead of through the default constructor?

I fixed the code format. Please look how I did it so you don't have this problem in the future.

Is MixedFractions::GetWholeNum doing some kind of IO to read a whole number? Does MixedFractions::SetWholeNum do something observable outside the current function, like print something?

the question is unclear. There is nothing obviously wrong with the code you show. Does it work? Does it compile?

though, the code is also not doing anything useful (at least not obviously), the method creates some objects, calls methods on them and when the method returns those objects are destroyed, no information flows in or out of the method (unless in parts not shown here)

class MixedFractions MixedFrac1, MixedFrac2, MixedFracSum; you don't need the class  on this line. MixedFractions MixedFrac1, MixedFrac2, MixedFracSum; should be sufficient and there is nothing special about creating additional objects of the same type inside a class member function.

The question isn't clear. What is the expected output and how does it differ from current output? Also a [mcve] would be good.

You seem to be missing inputs and outputs. Normally this would be spelled something like MixedFractions operator-(MixedFractions lhs, MixedFractions rhs), and you probably need to deal with the fractional part as well as the whole number part.

See What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?

Naming classes in plural form rather than singular very often leads astray, and so does naming member functions as nouns rather than verbs.

Can we declare an object of a class inside a function of the same class in C++?

If I understand the question correctly, you're asking if you can define local variables of type MixedFractions within member functions of MixedFractions.
The answer is yes. class MixedFractions MixedFrac1, MixedFrac2, MixedFracSum; does indeed define three variables. They're all initialized with the default constructor.
There is one important exception to this rule, and that's obvious if you think about it. If you try to create a local variable of type MixedFractions in a constructor of MixedFractions, that would call another constructor for MixedFractions, which probably will quickly end up in a Stack Overflow.

You don't need the class specifier on the variable declarations: MixedFractions MixedFrac1, MixedFrac2, MixedFracSum;

(Nitpick mode: creating a local variable of type T within the destructor T::~T() will lead to similar problems.)

Okay thank you, follow-up question, how would I get this to work if a user creates two objects of this type but I need to access the member variables to use them for a function like the one above?

@AlbertPenaCharrez: See the comment above, and your C++ textbook. This function really should be named operator-.
